# CALayer mask - combining two layers

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, core-animation, calayer

In my app i have a view and i want it to have a small transparent gradients on left and right side. I am able to create either left or right gradient pretty easily, but i dont know how to combine them :

```
CAGradientLayer *rightLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
rightLayer.frame = self.bounds;
rightLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, nil];
rightLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.8f, 1.0f);
rightLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

CAGradientLayer *leftLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
leftLayer.frame = self.bounds;
leftLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, nil];
leftLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
leftLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.2f, 1.0f);


self.layer.mask = leftLayer;
```

As you can see, the problem is that i must assign only 1 layer to mask and i want it to have 2 layers. How do i merge leftLayer and rightLayer? Or how do i add both of these layers to mask?

Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create *one* gradient layer with a gradient that goes from clear to white to clear again and set the `locations` for the three points. So you will have to set the `endPoint` to be at the other side of your view (cover the entire width) by setting it to 1.

You need to wrap your points in NSValue objects to add them to the locations array, like this: `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myCGPoint];`

<s>Since the locations are defined between 0 and 1. You will have to calculate the values depending on the width of the layer you are masking. Something like this:</s>

```
0.2/width         // left edge
(width-0.2)/width // right edge
```

You are already setting the start and end point in the range of 0 to 1 so just use the same values.

Comment: hmmm...i've already tried that. I set colors but when i cant add cgpoints to locations...how do i do this?

Comment: @animal_chin Add a NSValue like this: `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myCGPoint];`

Comment: done it! final solution looks like this :

CAGradientLayer *combined = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    combined.frame = self.bounds;
    combined.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, nil];
    combined.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
    combined.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

maybe setting locations will improve a bit but for me this works just fine :)

Comment: but is it possible to combine two layers? lets say he has way more complex layers than just 2 gradients

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use "locations" as mentioned by the others. The code below does a "fade out" gradient in the top and the bottom -- useful if you want to have scrolling text fade out of your screen in both ends. The location stops below should be read as 0.0 => 0.1 is fade from clear to white and then 0.9 => 1.0 is fade from white to clear again.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @0.1, @0.9, @1.0];

[self.layer setMask:gradient];
```

Remember to include `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your file.